# lambda disk limitation of just 6mb

Tags: aws-lambda

I made a lambda function to download an excel file can be 10-50mb and somehow I discover that lambda have a limitation of just 6mb. My project is already near completion just missing download over 6mb...

How do you even integrate lambdas on APIs if you can't even use it to download some files? Is there a solution?

> [ERROR] [1654098739375] LAMBDA_RUNTIME Failed to post handler success
> response. Http response code: 413. Failed to post invocation
> response.Response code: '413'.:
>
> lambdainternal.runtimeapi.LambdaRuntimeClientException
> lambdainternal.runtimeapi.LambdaRuntimeClientException: Failed to post
> invocation response.Response code: '413'.

Comment: lambdas were not designed for it, what you can do is to put your excel file into S3 and send back a presigned URL for the user, and the user would download the file directly from s3, or you can just ignore lambda and put your file into s3

Answer (score 0):

Lambdas have 512 MB of temporary storage in `/tmp` that you can use.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/choosing-between-aws-lambda-data-storage-options-in-web-apps/

If you need more, you can mount an EFS filesystem to them, for functionally unlimited space.